# Merge two models grouped by month

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have to models and they are grouped by months:

```
$cars= $company->car->groupBy(function($item)
{
     return Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->format('M');
});

$boats= $company->boat->groupBy(function($item)
{
     return Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->format('M');
});
```

So I got two collection

```
  Collection {#841 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    "Jan" => Collection {#848 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => Cars {#859 ▶}
      ]
    }
    "Fab" => Collection {#852 ▶}
    "Mar" => Collection {#853 ▶}
  ]
}
```

And the same one for the boats, my question is how to merge them to get something like:

```
  Collection {#841 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    "Jan" => Collection {#848 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => Cars {#859 ▶}
        1 => Boats {#860 ▶}
      ]
    }
    "Fab" => Collection {#852 ▶}
    "Mar" => Collection {#853 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first merge those 2 collections and then group by month.

The following code should do the trick:

```
$result = $company->car->merge($company->boat)->groupBy(function($item) {
     return Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->format('M');
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for help but this is not working, I am gettings just collection of boats there...

Comment: I tested both ways locally and I'm getting correct results. Could you paste relation definition? Are you sure that both return results? Try first running that without groupby and see if you have elements of both types.

Comment: The problem was that they had same rows so they got overridden, this is correct answer only if you don't have same rows, if you do look at my solution below this post.

Comment: What do you mean by same rows?

Comment: Well car has: brand, year_of_manufacture, engine_power etc... and boat has same rows ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```
$collection= $company->car;
$company->boat->each(function ($item) use ($collection) {
    $collection->add($item);
});
```